# Replace a number in dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in which I occasionally have `-1`s. I want to replace them with `NA`. I tried the `apply` function, but it returns a matrix of characters to me, which is no good:

```
 apply(d,c(1,2), function(x){
   if (x == -1){
      return (NA)
   }else{
      return (x)
   }
 })
```

I am wrestling with `by` but I cannot seem to handle it properly. I have got this so far:

```
 s <-by(d,d[,'Q1_I1'], function(x){
     for(i in x)
        print(i)
})
```

which if I understood correctly `by()` serves into `x` my dataframe row by row. And I can iterate through the each element of the row by the `for` function. I just don't know how to replace the value.

Comment: `d[d == -1] <- NA`

Comment: Thanks! I hoped there is an easier solution.

Comment: Easier? What do you mean?

Comment: Easier/shorter than how I approached the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that `apply` does not work is that it converts a data frame to a matrix and if your data frame has any factors then this will be a character matrix.

You can use `lapply` instead which will process the data frame one column at a time.  This code works:

```
mydf <- data.frame( x=c(1:10, -1), y=c(-1, 10:1), g=sample(letters,11) )
mydf
mydf[] <- lapply(mydf, function(x) { x[x==-1] <- NA; x})
mydf
```

As @rawr mentions in the comments it does work to do:

```
mydf[ mydf== -1 ] <- NA
```

but the documentation (`?'[.data.frame'`) say that that is not recommended due to the conversions.

One big question is how the data frame is being created.  If you are reading the data using `read.table` or related functions then you can just specify the `na.strings` argument and have the conversion done for you as the data is read in.

Comment: @Pio, if you are reading with `read.csv` then you can set `na.strings= -1` and they will be converted to `NA` when you read in the data and you will not need to do the post editing.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this fast and transparently with the data.table library.

```
# take standard dataset and transform to data.table
mtcars = data.table(mtcars,keep.rownames = TRUE)

# select rows with 5 gear and set to NA
mtcars[gear==5,gear:= NA]
mtcars
```